# Диалект SQL для DBase

Tags: delphi, база-данных, sql

Где найти описание диалекта SQL для DBase (BDE или MS DBase)? В частности, строковые функции.

Answer (score 1):

См. [сюда](http://www.dbase.com/help/Plus-en.htm) - фтыкайте в районе главы Local SQL

*Небольшой оффтопик:
Читая Hashcode иногда натыкаюсь на такие жОсткие оксюмороны! Я наивно полагал, что dBase умер еще во времена перехода dBase от Ashton Tate к Fox Software - ан нет! Жив курилка!*